# how do I do a post hoc Tukey on excel after doing a two way ANOVA with replication?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

on excel I did a two way ANOVA with replication (is this the same as two way repeated measures ANOVA?) and need to do a post hoc Tukey. How do I do this in excel 2016?

days represent the score on the day the measurement was taken

| treatment | day6 | day7 | day10 | day11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 30 | 500 | 490 |
| 1 | 2 | 400 | 900 | 500 |
| 1 | 3 | 32 | 1000 | 145 |
| 2 | 67 | 56 | 45 | 89 |
| 2 | 54 | 67 | 67 | 23 |
| 2 | 78 | 77 | 68 | 90 |
| 3 | 32 | 32 | 34 | 99 |
| 3 | 56 | 58 | 103 | 23 |
| 3 | 17 | 45 | 115 | 1043 |

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Post sample data and explain in brief what you want.

Comment: Sorry about that, I will post sample data. Essentially I did the data analysis using excel's built in two way ANOVA with replication and want to do a post hoc Tukey's test